# Replacing a value in a column based on the value in the column above

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has a column where some values are `See Above` or `See Below`. The data frame looks something like this:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Cat'], [1, 'See Above'], [4, 'See Below'],[2, 'Dog']], columns=['A','B'])

In[2]: df
Out[2]: 

    A   B
0   1   Cat
1   1   See Above
2   4   See Below
3   2   Dog
```

How could I update these values based on the value in the row above or below? I have ~2300k rows for context.

Comment: What if you had Cat/See Below/See Above/Dog?

Comment: @mozway that's a great question. Fortunately, I don't have that issue in my data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# mask as nan value that are 'see above' and then ffill
df['B']=df['B'].mask(df['B'].eq('See Above'), np.nan).ffill()

# mask as nan value that are 'see below' and then bfill
df['B']=df['B'].mask(df['B'].eq('See Below'), np.nan).bfill()
df
```

```
    A   B
0   1   Cat
1   1   Cat
2   4   Dog
3   2   Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single line with `replace`:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].replace('See Above',np.nan).ffill().replace('See Below',np.nan).bfill()
print(df)
```

**Result**

```
   A    B
0  1  Cat
1  1  Cat
2  4  Dog
3  2  Dog
```